# How do i merge these two collections in the same database to look like a single document

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, merging-data

I am working on an inventory management app. I have to collections in my database. One contains the product information uploaded along with the username like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60c6f5d5a9304624908d2b9f"),
"username" : "valorant",
"id" : 1231331414,
"barcode" : "1234434",
"productName" : "Fuse",
"price" : 1321,
"quantity" : 12314,
"__v" : 0
```

}

and there is another collection that has the user data and an array called 'store' where the product information uploaded by them has to be saved accordingly with respect to their usernames. I want to merge these systematically. the User collection looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b895a2ccaf390c88932eec"),
     "store" : [],
    "username" : "valorant",
    "email" : "valo@123.com",
    "job" : "Product Seller",
    "password" : "$2a$08$oD1LOM1nEXIqpF7LpwbVVui3NFlQxpzySrNsi5dX85sM/KqmdCzPC",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Please give the solution using mongoose and Javascript

I am trying to wrap my head around this issue but unable to get it. Any useful help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Please give the solution"* Maybe provide us with some of your attempt(s) so we can help you understand and solve the problem. SO is not a free coding service. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am Sorry @Reyno that you couldn't get my question. But I have no idea where to start this collections branching. So I just want help

Answer (score 0):

To connect between collections you better use _id (**which generated default by MongoDB**).
For example, to store user products you can create a collection that looks like this:

```
{
 _id:ObjectId("60b895a2ccaf390c88932eec"),
 product_id:"sdb895a2ccaf390c889485fd",
 user_id:"80b895a2ssaf390c88932ffc",
 //You can use other information
}
```

This method makes it easy to handle collections and manage data and you can create so much collection which is connected together.
To find user products you can use this code:

```
db.products.find({user_id:"80b895a2ssaf390c88932ffc"});
```

Comment: OK I will do it that way but how do I merge those respective products from products collection into that user's one

Comment: You can use this aggregation in MongoDb $lookup.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/